# difference between having a click handler on a button or on its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility

Between

```
<button onClick={...}>Click me</button>
```

and

```
<span onClick={...}>
  <button>Click me</button>
</span>
```

are there any differences for the user? I know that the click event will always bubble up to the `span` element, but are there any accessibility issues or unintended consequences that could arise from this?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I have put an answer as to why not to do it but I would like to help with whatever is causing you to want to do this and see if I can help you come up with a valid solution!

Comment: @GrahamRitchie dealing with a libraries shenanigans. There is no high level question here, just want to know if there is a difference between these exact two snippets for the user.

Answer (score 5):

There is a massive difference!

If you tab to a `<button>` so it is focused you can activate it using <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will activate the click handler. It will not do this with a `<span>` (even if you add `tabindex="0"` to the `<span>` so it is focusable).

Also having a click handler on a `<span>` around a `<button>` will cause issues as you then have nested active elements. This means that when you click on the `<button>` that is within a `<span>` there is no way of knowing which element is supposed to fire an event (is it the `<span>` click handler or the `<button>` click handler?)

The question is, **why** do you want to attach the handler to the `<span>` as it may be that there is a better way to do what you are attempting. Let me know and I will see if I can help you structure things better / work around the problem!

Comment: in both snippets, there is a button aka something to tab to. Styling wise, these also look identical since <span> is an inline element and there are no other children. 
The question is not **why** I want to do this. The question is if there is functionally a difference between these exact two snippets.

Comment: No problem @cubefox I think I have answered the differences then (but if you need any more info just let me know), and I can understand the headaches of library quirks all too well, hopefully you find a simple workaround 

Answer (score 1):

since your question is about accessibility, you sure shouldn't do this because you have a native element for "clicking things" in HTML, but if you insist you can make a span work as a button by:

- adding the role='button' attribute
- handle the aria-pressed attribute value
- define a value for tabindex attribute.

if you didn't do this the screen readers users will have a difficult time in your website

this link contains an example how button can be considered a div with extra attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role

Comment: there is a button inside the span.

Comment: there is indeed a button inside the span, which is what should be the target for focus and clicks, but (as Muhammed says) "if you insist..." you can make the span into a button. He didn't mention that you should then also remove the button. Better still, just use the button.

Answer (score -2):

In that setup, you should be fine. If however you had a `<span>` inside of the `<button>`, then that's when you'll run into issues because a button should not contain children elements, only the value.

`<button type="button" onclick="alert("Yo");"></button>`
= works

`<button type="button"><span onclick="alert("Yo");"></button>` = fails

And then I believe Firefox handles these events differently to Chrome, but the latest builds should be ok.

Comment: [Buttons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) can absolutely contain child elements. They can contain any non-interactive [phrasing elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content) including spans, images, canvas elements, SVGs, etc.

Comment: @Sean You misunderstood me. Buttons can indeed contain many different types of elements, but this question is relating to a Javascript onclick event, not buttons in particular, for which my answer is 100% correct.

Answer (score -3):

when you call the onclick on `span` you dont need to use `event.preventDefault`. but when you use `button` or `a` you need to use `event.preventDefault`. that the basic difference

Answer (score -4):

Why do you need the button element?  Just use <span onclick="onClick()> You can style the span with css.  Personally I think button is redundant.

Comment: So a `<button>` element has semantic meaning to people who use assistive technology such as a screen reader. Additionally a `<button>` is focusable for keyboard users where a `<span>` is not (unless you start using `tabindex`), a click handler acts differently on a `<span>` than it would on a `<button>`, if you add a `<button>` to a `<form>` it will submit the form, any questions just ask! There are lots of reasons to use a `<button>` rather than a `<span>`, the main one being accessibility! By the way could you delete your duplicate answer you made earlier to keep things tidy please?

Comment: Thanks for that - good points.

Comment: surely it's the *span* which is redundant here, not the button!